# Where do I change the windows xp log in menu?

Tags: windows, login, windows-xp

I am using windows XP, and for some reason I find myself with an old dialog box to login, which doesn´t even allow me to select an account. I used to have the classic menu coming with Xp.

I know I have to change an option somewhere, but I find myself unable to spot it ...

Could you tell me where it is ?

To sum up with images, I had this :

[image]

And now I have that :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You joined a windows server domain, or you/something have/has changed the way to login, a property of the user account settings in Control Panel:

Control Panel > User Accounts > Change login behaviour > check "Use welcome screen".

Comment: I think you're right, when I reach the menu, I got a message telling me that "client service for Netware" had disable the welcome message. Would you have an idea about why on earth this think poped out ?

Comment: No, no experience with. Ask them?

Comment: Who do you mean by ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I presumed you knew how NetWare got on your system and that it's from Novell. Again, I'm unfamiliar with it or them, but you could try getting info [from their site](http://www.novell.com/products/clients/windows/xp2000/overview.html). Or maybe someone from here can help you further.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Actually somebody had been using the computer, and he connected it to an iPhone, after installing some software. I think this is where the matter comes from. Anyway, the "use welcome screen" option was locked, but I could unlock it by uninstalling the "client service for Netware"  (with the procedure described there : http://www.ehow.com/how_7619781_uninstall-netware-client.html). Then I could put things back to normal. Thanks again for your help !